# A-Frame: Programmatically taking panoramic screenshots

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, aframe

Following docs here for panoramic screen shots https://aframe.io/blog/screenshot/
they have hot keys for users taking screen shots,
is there a way for me to generate a panoramic screenshot without user input?

as well as choosing to save it (server side).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take screen captures programatically using the methods outlined in the following documentation: https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/components/screenshot.html#methods

To take a screenshot programatically and get a canvas, call getCanvas():

```
// `screenshot.projection` property can be `equirectangular` or `perspective`.
document.querySelector('a-scene').components.screenshot.getCanvas('equirectangular');
```

To take a screenshot programmatically and automatically save the file, call capture():

```
document.querySelector('a-scene').components.screenshot.capture('perspective');
```

Answer (score 0):

Server side and without user interaction you will need something a bit heavier e.g. https://github.com/AdaRoseCannon/ff-a-frame-snap using Selenium to open up Firefox and take equirectangular screenshots thanks to Node.